# After Apache sets up reverse proxy, the default home page will be invalid

Tags: apache

My server environment is Apache, version is Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

The site configuration file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) - [END]
    # Else proxy
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:60000/$1 [P,QSA]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:60000/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access the directory with only the index.php file, it will be reverse proxy，Did not parse index.php

If I change the DirectoryIndex to index.php index.html , the problem will be solved, but the above problem will occur in index.html.

And when I delete the reverse proxy, both index.php and index.html will be normal and will not be affected by the order.

So the problem might be: Apache only recognizes the first DirectoryIndex when the reverse proxy exists, and if it doesn't exist, it will reverse proxy instead of trying the default home page behind it.

I hope that the default home page and reverse proxy can coexist peacefully. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

After several explorations, I tried other ways to achieve my function.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    RewriteEngine on
    #
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.php -f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1/index.php [P,END]
    #
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) - [END]
    # Else proxy
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:60000/$1 [P,QSA]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:60000/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

As with the above configuration, I only keep a default home page and use the reverse proxy method to implement the display of other default home pages.

But obviously, this is not necessarily the best way, I hope partners with better ways can inform